# How to keep "Local History" when I rename/move the project folder to a different location?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have my project in the folder path `path/to/project-folder-A`.
And I want to move/rename my project folder to another path `new/path/to/project-folder-B`.

When I do so, [Local History](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history) entries disappear  from the timeline view.

Before moving/renaming project's folder:
[image]

After:
[image]

How can I **keep the local history entries** of project's files when I move/rename the project folder either on the same machine or to another machine?

Edit: I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152415).

Comment: Git does not have "local history" like this; this question is specific to VSCode.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, you will probably have to file a feature request.